# Can this be considered as a repeated measures ANOVA?

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose I have three subjects $A,B$ and $C$, and I wish to see the response of the subject to a certain treatment during two periods of time $T1$ and $T2$. for the period $T1$, if a subject, let's say, $A$ has a response to this treament, then subject $B$ is going to have a response that depend on that of subject $A$. The same thing goes for subject $C$. The subjects are not Normal distributed.

Can this experment be designed as a RM-ANOVA?

Comment: I am having trouble with your explanation of the details. Are you really saying the subjects do not respond independently of one another? If that is true then there is a special technical term for your design: **_mess_**. Also, lack or normality can be a problem in ANOVA designs. Finally, the term _repeated measures_ is used quite differently in different fields of application. It would be best if you wrote the model for the design you're asking about.

Comment: @BruceET? yes, the subjects do not respond independently of one another. I guess that this answers my question.

Comment: @BruceET What about if the factors don't repond independently?

Comment: Can't see what that would mean. If $n$ subjects take two tests and answer independently of one another, then it's a paired t design. If $n$ subjects take three tests, then I'd say it's a block design (subjects are random blocks), tests are fixed, everything crossed. Vector for Test1 would be correlated with vector for Test 2. (Smart subjects would score higher on both, etc.) This is a little like calling into a dermatologist and saying "I have a pink rash, what do you suppose it might be?"

Comment: Are the responses of $B$ and $C$ conditionally independent of each other given the responses of $A$?  $\qquad$

Comment: Maybe at stats (dot) stackexchange (dot) com this would get better answers.  It might involve issues that would be lost on mere (or pure) mathematicians. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy The response of each subject depend on the others.

Comment: @BruceET I have more than 2 treatments (I mentioned 2 treatments for my example forgetting that it's a t test), I'm trying to see if I can fit my experiment into a within subject experiment design.